# Can design by contract allow me to enforce private methods

Tags: c#, .net, design-by-contract

I can't do this with language 
[How to enforce private method since interface methods are only public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765541/how-to-enforce-private-method-since-interface-methods-are-only-public)

so can I use design by contract instead ?

Comment: @user310291: Updated my answer in your previous question

Comment: Please explain why you want to do that. I can't see no reason what so ever to do that.

Comment: I already explained in previous post: it's for enforcing coding style for Internal team not external team.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are interested in enforcing a particular coding style, naming conventions, or things like that you are better off implementing custom rules for tools like [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [StyleCop](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis).** There really aren't any features in either the C# language or the .NET environment to help you enforce such things.

However, before you go to such lengths, you should really ask yourself whether the *automated enforcement of such standards are sufficiently valuable to warrant the expense and difficulty of a solution*. Are you dealing with a large team (dozens of developers) or a small one? Could simpler alternatives like code reviews be a sufficient means to enforce this? How will this kind of enforcement affect the over quality of the code vs. productivity/happiness of your team? What are the consequences of these standards aren't enforced?

These are important questions to consider before implementing such enforcement.